# For Loop to Switch Sections Functions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a slideshow using CSS/Javascript. I have a for loop within the functions for nextSlide and prevSlide. I'm having trouble trying to actually execute, alerts within the function work before the for loop.

https://jsfiddle.net/ethacker/b7cyv7xh/

JS code:

```
//Fetal Dev
    //Variables
var previous = document.getElementById('pPage');
var next = document.getElementById('nPage');
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('fdSlide');
var activeSlide = slide[0];
activeSlide.style.display = 'inline'; //shows "slide[0]"
//for loop
/*for (i=1; i<slide.length; i++) {
    var activeSlide = slide[i];
    var nextSlide = slide[i] + 1;
    var prevSlide = slide[i] - 1;
}

activeSlide.style.display = 'inline';*/

//Functions

function switchPrev() {
    for (i=0; i<slide.length; i++) {
          var prevSlide = slide[i]-1;
    }

    activeSlide = slide[prevSlide];
}

function switchNext(){
    for (i=0; i<slide.length; i++) {
        var nextSlide = slide[i]+1;
    }

    activeSlide = slide[nextSlide];
}


//Event Listeners
previous.addEventListener("click", switchPrev);
next.addEventListener("click", switchNext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop is probably the wrong construct for this. Retain the index as a variable and use it to gain access to your slide.

```
var ndx = 0,
    slides = document.getElementsByClassname(...),
    activeSlide = slides[ndx];
```

And when you need to increment or decrement...

```
var incrementSlide = function () {
    ndx++;
    ndx = ndx ℅ slides.length;
    activeSlide = slides[ndx];

    // Swap out old and new slide here
}

var decrementSlide = function () {
    ndx--;
    ndx = ndx℅ slides.length;
    activeSlide = slides[ndx];

    // Swap out old and new slide here
}
```

Comment: I get it up until ndx = % slides.length, what is that for?

Comment: The % allows us to continue incrementing and not have to worry about overflowing. It is a modulo operation, used to wrap around the array to the other side. 2 % 4 is 2, as is 6 % 4.